# Use chrome network panel like firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

There is a "Persist" in Net panel in Firefox. It can keep the logs even when page reloads or redirects. That's cool. Can I do the same thing in chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a black dot icon in the bottom toolbar with a tooltip 'Preserve Log upon Navigation' that should do the same thing. Should be to the left of the clear icon.

Comment: Thanks! Wish it was a bit more obvious! Especially seeing as Console's setting is under the "Cog" Settings menu!